# Why it takes so much time to test a sentence using Stanford NER model?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I use a corpus which contains around 400 sentences to train a CRF model of stanford core nlp. The training time is about 7 to 11 seconds. When I use this model to verify some new sentences, it cost around 0.6 seconds per sentence and each sentence has 10 tokens on average. I think it's too slow that using 0.6s to label one sentence, so, how can I improve the performance?

Comment: Can you please provide more details about how you are calling Stanford CoreNLP.

Comment: Also, how many classes does your model have ?